# what could caise a Rattling noise while accelerating if the AC is on?

Tags: suzuki, rattle

I have a Suzuki Celerio and since last week I noticed that there is a rattling noise from the engine bay while accelerating. It only happens when the AC is turned on. I have also noticed that the fuel efficiency has gone down considerably. Any suggestions as to why it is happening and probable ways to fix this issue!

Comment: It seems from what you are saying the rattling noise could be "knocking" or "pining" due to pre-ignition inside the cylinder. When too much stress is put onto smaller engines, this can occur. A/C being on could be that tipping point. A thorough induction cleaning could help here.